# Awk: move files when they meet a certain criterion

Tags: file, awk, conditional-statements, move

I'm trying to figure out a way to move a bunch of files into a subdirectory when they meet an *if* criterion/condition with awk. Do you know how it can be done?

```
 for f in *.txt; do awk '{if ( $1 == "rainbow" && $3 == "unicorn" && $4 == "murder" && $5 == "vampire") print FILENAME}' $f; done
```

instead of printing the filename, I would like my code to move the files to a certain directory.

Thanks

Comment: Did either of my suggestions work for you? If so, could you accept one of them as the answer please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you could let awk do the move for you, if you replace your

```
print FILENAME
```

with

```
system("mv " FILENAME " " OtherDirectory)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following directly after the end of your command:

```
| while read f; do mv "$f" SomeOtherDirectory; done
```

Initially, you may want to change the "mv" into "echo" to see what the command will do before actually executing it.